Haskell Typeclass for non-transative equality
I know that the laws for the Eq class include reflectivity, symmetry, and transitivity.  Is there another class for the case where equality is not necessarily transitive?
I could write one myself (see below), but I'm wondering if competent mathematicians/developers have already explored this space before me.
class SubEq a where
  (=~=) :: a -> a -> Bool

data Uncertain = Uncertain Int Int

instance SubEq Uncertain where
  (Uncertain x y) =~= (Uncertain a b) = 
    (x < a && x < b && y < a && y < b)
    || (x > a && x > b && y > a && y > b)

(±) :: Int -> Int -> Uncertain
a ± b = Uncertain (a-b) (a+b)

main = do
  let a = 5 ± 2
  let b = 7 ± 7 
  let c = 10 ± 2
  print $ (a =~= b) -- True: 6 exists in both sets
  print $ (b =~= c) -- True: 9 exists in both sets
  print $ (a =~= c) -- False: No number satisfies both a and c

Note that the above code is only a rough sketch to demonstrate what I'm looking for in a SubEq style class.  I haven't actually run it through a compiler and probably contains typos.

I can not immediately find something for an "overlap" relation, which is essentially what you are doing iiuic?

In this specific instance, I'm looking at an overlap of bounds, but it's come up in a few other contexts over the years.  One example I saw mentioned elsewhere was the "likes" function.  Edward likes Bella = True, Bella likes Jacob = True,  but Edward likes Jacob = False;.  Technically, the original example was "kissed", but that fails are being reflexive.

For terminology and math background, a relation that's reflexive and transitive is sometimes called a "coherence relation", which is usually used to describe a "coherence space" (not to be confused with a "coherent space," which is something else). The general idea is that two things are related by the relation if they represent "pieces of information" that are "consistent" with each other. This is usually studied in the context of linear logic.

(^ a typo: that should say "[...] a relation that's reflexive and symmetric [...]")

A dependency relation is reflexive and symmetric.
